# Grouping same values from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter, reduce

```
let array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];
```

i want to group double values from array, to get result like this:

result: 
`['3a, 2b, c']`
(or something similar)

Any idea?

Comment: do you want really a single string in an array as result? what have you tried?

Comment: @NinaScholz exactly that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.reduce()` and `.map()` methods:

```js
let array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];

let result = Object.entries(
    array.reduce((r, c) => (r[c] = (r[c] || 0) + 1, r) , {})
).map(([k, v]) => v == 1 ? k : v + k);

console.log(result);
```

You can also use `Map` if you need items in specific order:

```js
let array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];

let result = (((arr, map) => {
    arr.forEach(s => map.set(s, (map.get(s) || 0) + 1));
    return [...map.entries()].map(([k, v]) => v == 1 ? k : v + k);
})(array, new Map()));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a dictionary to track the duplicate values in the array.

```
var dictionary = {};
for(var i = 0;i < array.length;i++){
   var value = array[i];
   if(dictionary[value] === undefined){
      dictionary[value] = 0;
   }
   dictionary[value] = dictionary[value] + 1;

}
console.log(dictionary)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function count() {
array_elements = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "c", "f", "g", "h", "h", "h", "e", "a"];
array_elements.sort();
var current_elements = null;
var count= 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array_elements.length; i++) {
    if (array_elements[i] != current_elements) {
        if (cnt > 0) {
            console.log(current_elements+count);
        }
        current_elements= array_elements[i];
        count= 1;
    } else {
        count++;
    }
}
if (cnt > 0) {
    console.log(current_elements+count);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A single loop approach for simple [run-length encoding (RLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) function.

```js
let array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'],
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, c, i, a) => r.concat(c === a[i - 1]
            ? ((+r.pop().slice(0, -1) || 1) + 1) + c
            : c),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` to produce an object with key-value (array value and count) pairs, then `Array.map()` to produce an array using `Object.keys()`.

```js
let array = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];

let countObj = array.reduce((acc, val) => (acc[val] = acc[val] ? acc[val] + 1 : 1, acc), {});

console.log(countObj);

let countArr = Object.keys(countObj).map(key => '' + countObj[key] + key);

console.log(countArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

For "something similar" why not just have an object that maps letter to occurrence. You can then simply use dot notation to get the property value assigned to each key.

Here I've used [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const arr = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c'];

// `reduce` over the arr
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // If the object (acc) we passed in doesn't have
  // a key assigned to the letter in the current
  // iteration (c) add it, set it to 0, then
  // add one, otherwise, if there is a key, add one
  acc[c] = (acc[c] || 0) + 1;

  // Return the object for the next iteration
  return acc;

// Pass in an initial object 
}, {});

console.log(obj);

// Grab the value of `a` property
console.log(obj.a);
```